# download a file using a downloadable link into webView android

Tags: android, webview

I want to download a file using a direct downloadable link into my webview.
my links is "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0Bw6vr2LNxB3iUFJrTk5oZDljaTA&export=download". if i open this link using a default browser then the browser automatically download the file.
I dont want to open the default web browser so i want to use the webview.
I tried this code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                    long contentLength) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Request request = new Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download"); 
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);   

            }
        });
```

I put a toast inside the setDownloadListener but the toast doesn't appear which means setDownloadListener doesn't work here?
Can anybody tell me how to solve the issue?
I have stack with this problem for a long time but cant able to solve.